# NestJS, drop controllers or routes in production

Tags: typescript, backend, nestjs

In my previous projects (before using NestJS), I built one useful utility called "route-collector". Basically, it just recursively collects and attaches routes to the Express app. I can change it's behaviour using ts decorators and metadata reflection API, for instance:

```
@Controller("/test")
class TestController {
  @Test
  @Get("/")
  private testRoute() {
    // code
  }
}
```

The `@Test` decorator would make route-collector "ignore" the `testRoute` if **NODE_ENV** was set to **production**.
I would like to get this behavior in NestJS, but cannot come up with the code.

Has anyone implemented something like that? If so I'd love to get some tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an global guard. (https://docs.nestjs.com/guards)

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: TestGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

test guard:

```
export class TestGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const testOnly =  this.reflector.get<boolean>('testonly', context.getHandler());
    // return false if node_env is prod and the test decorator is set
 }
}
```

The decorator would be like this:

```
export const Test = () => SetMetadata('testonly', true);
```